# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException when getting ssl connnection to mysql from tomcat application

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, java-11, tomcat9

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException` been raised when attempting to make an SSL connection to MySQL from a tomcat-based application.

I have tried the same code in a Java class in the main method without tomcat (like a Java project in eclipse). This program works fine, i.e. I am able to get an SSL connection to the database.

Error code:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ibisdb74?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/home/directoryA/mysql_certs_latest4/keystore&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypass&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/home/directoryA/mysql_certs_latest4/truststore&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypass","root","root");

Exception trace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:/home/gom7kor/mysql_certs_latest4/truststore [keystore password was incorrect]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.getSSLSocketFactoryDefaultOrConfigured(ExportControlled.java:224)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:80)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:5170)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1676)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2108)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.getSSLSocketFactoryDefaultOrConfigured(ExportControlled.java:204)
    ... 23 more


Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    ... 27 more
```

I looked for a successful encrypted connection without an exception, even in the tomcat based application.

PS: I am getting this exception with a tomcat based application, but not in non-tomcat applications. And I am using jdk 11 and tomcat 9.

Comment: _"Cannot open file:/home/gom7kor/mysql_certs_latest4/truststore [keystore password was incorrect]"_ Are you sure your keystore password is correct?

Comment: Yes, It is correct and as I mentioned with above statements this code snippet worked fine with normal java file execution without tomcat. Is it something to be done with configuring the server.xml of tomcat?

Comment: Files in a `/home` directory are rather suspicious. Is tomcat running with a user account that has read-access to these files, and if so, are you sure it is the same file?

Comment: User has access to this file and yes it is same file.